# Exclude gradle tests by default

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build, build.gradle

In my gradle project, how can i configure gradle to not run tests by default. I know we can do that with command `gradle build -x test`. But i don't have any control over the command and anyone can build the project on production without excluding the tests, which can be nasty. So i want to configure the gradle so that when we run `gradle build`, it doesn't run the tests and we have to explicity specify the test task to run it. I'm building an application in Spring Boot framework.

Comment: You should just run `gradle assemble` then

Comment: *But i don't have any control over the command and anyone can build the project on production*

Comment: Whoever is running gradle should understand that the "build" task runs tests. If you don't want tests, run a different task!

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
test.enabled = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains('test') || gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains('check')
```

But this is a hack when really you should just run a task other than "build" eg: assemble, jar or classes

See the diagram [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/img/javaPluginTasks.png)

Comment: It's ugly and smart at the same time :D

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your project :

```
check.dependsOn.remove("test")
```

`gradle build` will build without the `test`task, `gradle test` will run the tests

Comment: This still runs tests on `gradle build` for me for some reason.

Comment: It's a Spring Boot project.